# ODBC for mdb/accdb: Error Code 193

Tags: windows-7, odbc, ms-access

1. I have a Win7-64 bit OS
2. I have MS Office 2010 32-bit installed

I manage the ODBC data sources via ControlPanel->SystemAndSecurity->AdministrativeTools->DataSources

In the UserDSN tab, I see an entry for "MS Access Database Microsoft Access Driver(*.mdb, *.accdb);

If I click on the 'remove' or 'configure' buttons for that entry, I get an Error code 193.

Note:

1. I ran AccessDatabaseEngine.exe to make sure I have the 32 bit dlls.
2. I can verify that the dlls exist in the 32 bit folder (Ex: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE14\ACEODBC.DLL)

What am I doing wrong?  Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. Basically if you run the C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe the messages go away since you are now looking at 32 bit odbc connections and not 64 bit ones (which are the default when going through the Windows7 64-bit GUI) –