# Error in loading MS Access drivers for Java application

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, odbc, jdbc-odbc

I have created a Swing application for company which connects to an Access database locally stored in the computer. The application works just fine in my computer and some other local computers, but when I was asked to deploy it on server I got this exception:

> java.sql.SQLException : Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error 193: (Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb), C:\PROGRA^2\COMMON^1\MICROS^1\OFFICE12\ACEODBC.DLL

How can I get around this error?

Comment: Error 193 is "ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT 193 (0xC1) %1 is not a valid Win32 application." Which ODBCAD32.exe did you use to configure the datasource, and are you running Java 32 or 64 bit? Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662478/odbc-for-mdb-accdb-error-code-193

Comment: i have installed 32 bit java in the system but when i run java command  it says could not open 'c:\program files \java\jre7\lib\jvm.cfg ...  but when i installed 64 bit java too but i only gave the path of 32 bit java in the environment variables

Comment: now java runs properly i do not why it does not run only by 32 bit present in program files(x86) ...  i have done the odbc 32 bit ony loaded it from sysWOW64 only ...

Comment: i think the problem is with the java .. please look into the error